# For what values of $k$ is the set linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For what values of $k$ is the following set linearly independent?
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & -1 & 3 \\
        2 & 3 & k \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I reduced it down to

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 7 \\
        0 & 1 & -3 \\
        0 & 0 & -5+k\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: when det(Matrix) is not zero (k is not 5)

Comment: your last row last column element should be non zero, so that rank of the matrix remains 3 and thus the set will be LI.

Comment: You ask about "the following set", but you don't present a set, you present a matrix. It's important in Mathematics generally, and in Linear Algebra particularly, to stick to the precise meanings of the words you use. If you mean that you want, say, the set of *columns* to be linearly independent, you should say that.

Comment: You haven't engaged with comments; you haven't engaged with Martin's answer, and you haven't "accepted" it by clicking in the check mark next to it; this amounts to abuse of this website. Please don't just dump a question here, and then run away and hide.

Answer (score 1):

If $k=5$ then your last matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 7 \\
0 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
which means that its rank is $2$ and the rows of this matrix (and also of the original matrix) are linearly dependent.

If $k\ne5$, you can divide the third row by $(k-5)$ (since $k-5\ne0$ in this case) to get
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 7 \\
0 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix is in [row echelon form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). It has three non-zero row. So the row is equal to $3$ and the rows are linearly independent. (And the same is true for the original matrix.)